# Mayapy.exe as python interpreter for SublimeREPL

Tags: python, maya, autodesk, sublimerepl, pymel

I've tried following SublimeREPL instructions for setting default_extend_env.

I tried:

"default_extend_env": 
{"PATH": "{PATH}:C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/bin/mayapy.exe"}

I also tried:
"default_extend_env":
        {"PATH": "{PATH}:C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/devkit/other/pymel/extras/completion/py"}

I wasn't sure what the difference was between default_extend_env and python_virtualenv_paths so I tried adding those file paths under "python_virtualenv_paths" as well.

With any of those combinations, I couldn't even get any of the python interpreter options available in SublimeREPL to load the pymel module.

The option "Python - virtualenv" under Tools>SublimeREPL>Python> doesn't do anything either. When I try the python/ipython option, the window pops up as expected.

I have my sublime project set up properly with Jedi and sublime-code-intel so auto completion works.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just gave it a shot on SublimeText 3 (on Mac, however), but I imagine it will work for you as well. It just looks like you got the PATH string messed up a bit.

I basically used this path

```
"default_extend_env": {"{PATH}:/Applications/Autodesk/maya2016/Maya.app/Contents/bin"},
```

and I assume it would be the following for you:

```
"default_extend_env": {"{PATH}:C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/bin"},
```

Le me know if this works out for you...